# Excel to SQL - Very large file

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have a excel workbook with two sheets. One sheet is maxed out and the other is over half way. In total there's about 1.7 million rows.

Can someone help me with getting this into sql format. I need to import this into my sql server. I can either use Workbench or PHPMyAdmin.

The excel file is 84MB.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to add me on skype or something then I could help you do this, but its quite a big thing the way I figure it.

Comment: I will be able to later, at about 7pm, GMT. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to save your data as CSV file (Excel allows to do it), then import data from the CSV file into specified table with [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement.

Also, have a look at this feature - [Data Import tool](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) (Excel format) in dbForge Studio for MySQL.